# Disabling Nagle's Algorithm in solaris

Tags: network-programming, solaris

Suppose I want to disable Nagle's algorithm( for real time transmission of data ) in Solaris where the connection between the processes are established using local-loop back, would it be a problem. As for my understanding local-loop in Solaris do have TCP Fusion enabled( somewhat similar to Unix Domain Sockets ) to reduce overhead of stack usage.
Are they correlated or they are mutually exclusive in nature ? My doubt is basically would it have any kind of repercussion ?

Also I would like some clarification that whether Nagle's algorithm could be disabled for local-loop back communication ?

I know I can use TCP_NODELAY. May be I need to clarify more: 1) What happens in local-loop back where Nagle's algorithm is disabled( by default its always enabled ). Will the TCP stack wait for MSS or it would immediately push the data out of the stack. 2) Also by default in solaris TCP fusion is enabled for faster read-write. Will it create any problem if Nagle is disabled. Finally what I want is data should be sent in real-time without any delay. So do I have to disable Nagle or TCP fusion is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I admit I don't know if naggle can be disabled only for 1 interface. At a global level, this would be done with the following command (but I guess you already know that):

```
/usr/sbin/ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_naglim_def 1
```

My Solaris VM is broken right now so I cannot test, but if we imagine that "lo0" is your loopback, would "/usr/sbin/ndd -set /dev/**lo0** tcp_naglim_def 1" work?

The recommended default being to keep Nagle enabled, can you disable it inside your application? It should be as simple as call setsockopt() with the TCP_NODELAY option.

Comment: No, I think it's pretty clear, you're more looking for something like ndd, but only disabling nagle on the loopback interface, not on the real ones, right?

Comment: Is disabling nagle required for loop-back ? Wont TCP fusion transfer data in real time ?